# porting conditions hash to use in new rails 3 active record query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading a Rails 2.3.5 app to Rails 3. I did not implemented the app, I am just upgrading it. I have found that the developer has used query hash in a way that it is difficult to change it without touching many files, which I want to avoid.

```
class A
    def method_1
        AnObject.find(:all, :conditions => {:param_1 => @param_1}.merge(specific_params))
    end

    def specific_params
       raise NoMethodError, "Subclasses must implement this method", "specific_params"
    end
end

class B < A
    def specific_params
        {param_B1 => false, param_B2 => true}
    end
end
```

There are many classes which inherit from A. I need to convert the query in class A to Rails 3. Could somebody please suggest the best way to to port this to Rails 3 without changing the classes which inherit from A implement specific_params method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AnObject.find(:all, :conditions => {:param_1 => @param_1}.merge(specific_params))
```

will work in Rails 3.

Or you could change it to where:

```
AnObject.where({:param_1 => @param_1}.merge(specific_params))
```

Comment: I need to convert it to AnObject.where(...) form

Comment: Why? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: According to [link]()In short, passing options hash containing :conditions, :include, :joins, :limit, :offset, :order, :select, :readonly, :group, :having, :from, :lock to any of the ActiveRecord provided class methods, is now deprecated.

Comment: Updated my answer to use where